# ¿Cómo mostrar todos los datos en filas secundarias con Child Rows en las Datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

Estoy haciendo una tabla a la cual le he agregado las datatables. Ahora bien, estas filas, cada una tendrá un checkbox, el cual, al chequearlo, se mostrarán los datos de esa fila en subfilas. Ya lo hice todo, extraigo los datos conforme lo seleccionado, pero tengo un problema, y es que no me extrae todos los datos, solamente me muestra el último dato. Si tengo 3 subdatos en la subfila solo me muestra el último.

Adjunto el código que estoy usando.

La función cargarTab la utilizo en cada cambio del "tab", mando a llamar la función para mostrar los datos que necesito del proveedor y le aplico el datatable

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#frmProveedor").click(function(){
        cargarFormulario();
    });

    cargarTab('loadProveedorGeneral','General');

    $('.nav-tabs .nav-link').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
        var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
        console.log(x);
        if (x == 'General') { cargarTab('loadProveedorGeneral','General'); }
        if (x == 'Nacionales') { cargarTab('loadProveedorNacional','Nacional'); }
        if (x == 'Internacionales') { cargarTab('loadProveedorInternacional','Internacional'); }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<div class="row bqProveedores" style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
        <span class="text-proveedores">Listado de Proveedores</span><br><br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <button class="nav-link active" id="general-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#general" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">General</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <button class="nav-link" id="nacionales-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#nacionales" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Nacionales</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <button class="nav-link" id="internacionales-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#internacionales" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Internacionales</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddProveedor" type="button" onclick="cargarFormulario()">
                    Crear Proveedor <i class="fas fa-plus" style="margin-left: 10px;"></i>
                </button>
                <div id="loadMdlProveedor"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="general" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="general-tab">
                <div id="loadProveedorGeneral"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nacionales" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nacionales-tab">
                <div id="loadProveedorNacional"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="internacionales" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="internacionales-tab">
                <div id="loadProveedorInternacional"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
    function cargarTab(cargar,tipoProveedor){
        $('#'+cargar).load("load/ajax/resultados/resProveedores?tipoProveedor="+tipoProveedor, function() {
            
            swal.close();

            var table = $('#tbl'+tipoProveedor).DataTable({
                paging: true,
                lengthChange: false,
                responsive: true,
                order: [[1,'asc']],
                searching: false,
                info: false,
                language: {
                    paginate: {
                        first:      "|<",
                        previous:   "<",
                        next:       ">",
                        last:       ">|"
                    },
                }
            });

            // Add event listener for opening and closing details
            $('#tbl' + tipoProveedor + ' tbody').on('click', 'td.check-control input.checkMarcas', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);
        
                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } else {
                    // Open this row
                    format(row.data(),row,tr);
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            });

        });
    }

    function format(d,row,tr) {
        var url = "../../modelo/read?id=OBT-MARCAS";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:url,
            data: {proveedorId: Number(d[1])},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                if(data.success){
                    
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
                    
                        // Crear la nueva subfila
                        let subRow = row.child($('<tr>'));

                        // Crear la tabla y sus filas y celdas
                        let subTable = $('<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-left:50px; margin-top: -10px;">');
                        let subRow2 = $('<tr>');
                        let subCell = $('<td>');
                        let subList = $('<ul>');
                        let subListItem = $('<li>');
                        
                        subListItem.text(data.datos[i][1]);
                        subList.append(subListItem);
                        subCell.append(subList);
                        subRow2.append(subCell);
                        subTable.append(subRow2);

                        // Agregar la tabla a la subfila
                        subRow.child(subTable).show();
                        
                    }

                } else {
                    sweetealerta('Lo siento!','Este proveedor no posee marcas disponibles','warning');
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: pon tu HTML, donde estas llamando a la funcion cargarTab??

Comment: Ya lo edite, ahi esta el fragmento html y el fragmento js donde mando a llamar la funcion cargarTab

Comment: te falta una función: 'cargarFormulario()', sin eso el código no se puede probar porque tira errores

Comment: Ya logré solventarlo, muchas gracias. Lo que hice fue que guarde los datos en un array y luego al mostrarlos solo los separé con 'join'